Check if enum is unit-only and contiguous
Rust language allows to create fancy enum variants like this:
enum MyEnum {
    UnitVariant,
    TupleLikeVariant(i32, i32),
    StructLikeVariant {
        a: i32,
        b: i32,
    },
}

Also rust allows enum's discriminants to have "holes" (to not be contiguous):
enum HalfLifeGame {
    // ... = 0
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    // ... = 3
    Alyx = 4,
}

How do I check that a given enum:
a) Is unit only (and not zero variant too)
b) Has no gaps in discriminants (i.e. all enum's discriminants correspond to some contiguous range 0..n)
?
Ideally I would prefer something like this:
const fn is_unit_only_and_contiguous<T>() -> bool
where
    /* T is enum */
{
    /* ... */
}


Those kind of properties are not expressible via available traits (not even "T is enum" exists). You would need to create a macro that is annotated on each enum that determines those criteria.

@kmdreko Could you please clarify how to determine all of this via a macro?

What is the purpose of knowing this information about an enum? Perhaps there is another way of achieving what you want.

Use the Contiguous derive macro from the bytemuck crate. The trait implementation it generates has methods for conversions if that's what you're after. Though it does require explicit #[repr(int)] annotations as well.
Here's how it could look in your code:
#[derive(Contiguous)]
#[repr(u8)]
enum MyEnum {
   A = 0,
   B = 1,
   C = 2,
}

And then use T: Contiguous where you'd like that constraint.

Not exactly what I was asking, but precisely what I was searching for. Thank you.
